# caret: using random forest and include cross-validation

Tags: random-forest, cross-validation, r-caret

I used the caret package to train a random forest, including repeated cross-validation. I’d like to know whether the OOB, as in the original RF by Breiman, is used or whether this is replaced by the cross-validation.  If it is replaced, do I have the same advantages as described in Breiman 2001, like increased accuracy by reducing the correlation between input data? As OOB is drawn with replacement and CV is drawn without replacement, are both procedures comparable? What is the OOB estimate of  error rate (based on CV)?

How are the trees grown? Is CART used?

As this is my first thread, please let me know if you need more details. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

There are a lot of basic questions here and you would be better served by reading a book on machine learning or predictive modeling. Thats probably why you haven't gotten much of a response.

For `caret` you should also consult the [package website](http://topepo.github.io/caret/) where some of these questions are answered.

Here are some notes:

- CV and OOB estimation for RF are somewhat different. [This post](http://appliedpredictivemodeling.com/blog/2014/11/27/vpuig01pqbklmi72b8lcl3ij5hj2qm) might help explain how. For this application, the OOB rate from random forest is computed while the model is being build whereas CV uses holdout samples that are predicted after the random forest model is computed.
- The original random forest model (used here) uses unpruned CART trees. Again, this is in many text books and papers.

Max

Answer (score 2):

I recently got a little confused with this too, but reading chapter 4 in Applied Predictive Modeling by Max Kuhn helped me to understand the difference.

If you use randomForest in R, you grow a number of decision trees by sampling N cases with replacement (N is the number of cases in the training set). You then sample m variables at each node where m is less than the number of predictors. Each tree is then grown fully and terminal nodes are assigned to a class based on the mode of cases in that node. New cases are classified by sending them down all the trees and then taking a vote; the majority vote wins.

The key points to note here are:

- how the trees are grown - sampling WITH replacement (a bootstrap). This means that some cases will be represented many times in your bootstrap sample and others may not be represented at all. The bootstrap sample will be the same size as your training dataset.
- The cases that are not selected for building trees are referred to as the OOB samples- an OOB error estimate is calculated by classifying the cases that aren't selected when building a tree.  About 63% of the data points in the bootstrap sample are represented at least once.

If you use caret in R, you will normally use caret::train(....) and specify the method as "rf" and trControl="repeatedcv". You can change trControl to "oob" if you want out of the bag. The way this works is as follows (I'm going to use a simple example of a 10 fold cv repeated 5 times): the training dataset is split into 10 folds of roughly equal size, a number of trees will be built using only 9 samples - so omitting the 1st fold (which is held out). The held out sample is predicted by running the cases through the trees and used to estimate performance measures. The first subset is returned to the training set and the procedure repeats with the 2nd subset held out, and so on. The process is repeated 10 times. This whole procedure can be repeated multiple times (in my example, I do this 5 times); for each of the 5 runs, the training dataset with be split into 10 slightly different folds. It should be noted that 50 different held out samples are used to calculate model efficacy.

The key points to note are:

- this involves sampling WITHOUT replacement - you split the training data and build a model on 9 samples and predict the held out sample (the remaining 1 sample of the 10) and repeat this process as above
- the model is built using a dataset that is smaller than the training dataset; this is different to the bootstrap method discussed above

You are using 2 different resampling techniques which will yield different results therefore they are not comparable. The k fold repeated cv tends to have low bias (for k large); where k is 2 or 3, bias is high and comparable to the bootstrap method. K fold cv tends to have high variance though...